# how can I move an object in Unity3D from one place to another and further in a set order by repeatedly pressing a single key?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

is there a way to move an object in Unity3d from one place (target1) to an other (target2.. so on) by pressing a key?

I used...

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{

    if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        transform.position = target1.position;

    }
}
```

...to move the Object form Start to the first target but if just would write another if statement the object would go directly to the target 2... :(

I want: Object moves from target1 to target2 to target3 and so on by pressing "s"

i hope someone can help me :)

Comment: furhter in a set order, you mean from point to point each time you press a key, correct?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're wanting to move an object by a fixed amount each time you press the key, in which case you'll want to first change GetKey() to GetKeyDown(), which will stop the function being called every frame while the key is held, and simply += a Vector3 to the transform.position.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay exactly! im a german psychologist and im trying to make a reaction test. the idea is that a cube moves on other cubes each time you hit s. (You have to stop on special blocks and the time it takes to move thru all the cubes is measured)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm understanding is either you want to have an array of places for your object to go, or you want the object to move a set amount each time you press a button. I will give an example and an explanation for each of these.

1. You want to move an object to different points, and not a specific amount each time.
   First off, you could use an array, and fill it with the places for the object to go, in order.
   Then, you could have a public variable for looping through the array everytime you press the button. Now, instead of `Input.GetKey("s")`, which has several problems, you want `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)`, because GetKeyDown only fires when you press the key, and GetKey fires every frame the key is pressed. You also want KeyCode, because that's what the KeyCodes are made for. Example code:

```
public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int index = 0;
    public Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[the amount of positions you have];
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.position = positions[index];
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

2. You want to move a fixed amount.

Use the same code, but without the array and int, and instead a Vector3 for how much you want to move. Then, in GetKeyDown, you'd do something like transform.position += moveAmount.

:)

PS: when asking a question on Stack Overflow, you should add a little bit more details, but it was a pretty good question, especially compared to others that I've seen.

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer. i typed all my positions in the arrays and when i hit s the first time it would move to the first position but when i hit it a second time it wont do anything I probably should have explained in my question that im a german psychologist and im trying to make a reaction test. the idea is that a cube moves on other cubes each time you hit s. (You have to stop on special blocks and the time it takes to move thru all the cubes is measured) but thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Did you use the exact code I posted? Because the fact that it doesn't move the second time makes me think that you forgot the index++ line.

Comment: i dont know how to thank you. i forgot the index++ line. Now it works exactly as i want it to. wish you the best for your life. many thanks for the answer <3